# HaltServer 'App failed to load.' when deploying to google cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I already tried a couple things, I'm not able to deploy my python api to Google Cloud and I don't know exactly what I need to change to get it working.

My project:

```
FlaskWebAPI 
- __pycache__ (folder)
- api (folder)
-- multiple files, for instance routes.py
- models (folder)
- resources (folder)
- tools (folder)
- .gcloudignore
- app.yaml
- app.py
- Procfile
- reload
- requirements.txt
- runtime.txt
```

My app.yml:

```
runtime: python38
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:flask_app
```

My app.py:

```
# flask packages
from flask import Flask, app
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager


# local packages
from api.routes import create_routes

# external packages
import os

# default mongodb configuration
default_config = {'MONGODB_SETTINGS': {
                    'db': '...',
                    'host': 'mongodb... #(url incl. user/password, the ones below are not in use I think)
                    'port': 27017,
                    'username': '...',
                    'password': '...',
                    'authentication_source': 'admin'},
                    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': '...'}


def get_flask_app(config: dict = None) -> app.Flask:
    """
    Initializes Flask app with given configuration.
    Main entry point for wsgi (gunicorn) server.
    :param config: Configuration dictionary
    :return: app
    """
    # init flask
    flask_app = Flask(__name__)



    # configure app
    config = default_config if config is None else config
    flask_app.config.update(config)
    
    # load config variables
    if 'MONGODB_URI' in os.environ:
        flask_app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'host': os.environ['MONGODB_URI'],
                                                'retryWrites': False}
    if 'JWT_SECRET_KEY' in os.environ:
        flask_app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['JWT_SECRET_KEY']

    # init api and routes
    api = Api(app=flask_app)
    create_routes(api=api)

    # init mongoengine
    db = MongoEngine(app=flask_app)

    # init jwt manager
    jwt = JWTManager(app=flask_app)

    return flask_app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Main entry point when run in stand-alone mode.
    app = get_flask_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Tried a couple things now, including renaming the app.py to main.py and changing the app.yml accordingly, with main:app at the end. But it all does not work (so far).

This is my latest error:

```
2021-12-13 20:12:04 default[20211213t210314]  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-12-13 20:12:04 default[20211213t210314]
2021-12-13 20:12:04 default[20211213t210314]  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>      sys.exit(run())    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run      WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run      super().run()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run      Arbiter(self).run()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run      self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt      self.stop()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop      time.sleep(0.1)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld      self.reap_workers()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 528, in reap_workers      raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)  gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>
2021-12-13 22:11:12 default[20211213t230919]  "GET /list/ HTTP/1.1" 500
2021-12-13 22:11:12 default[20211213t230919]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
2021-12-13 22:11:31 default[20211213t230919]  "GET /list/ HTTP/1.1" 500
2021-12-13 22:11:31 default[20211213t230919]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
2021-12-13 22:15:05 default[20211213t231221]  "GET /list/ HTTP/1.1" 500
2021-12-13 22:15:05 default[20211213t231221]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
2021-12-13 22:25:24 default[20211213t232324]  "GET /list/ HTTP/1.1" 500
2021-12-13 22:25:24 default[20211213t232324]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
2021-12-13 22:35:28 default[20211213t232918]  "GET /list/ HTTP/1.1" 500
2021-12-13 22:35:28 default[20211213t232918]  /bin/sh: 1: exec: gunicorn: not found
```

In an earlier instance I received a 502:

```
2021-12-13 20:05:30 default[20211213t210314]  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>      sys.exit(run())    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run      WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run      super().run()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run      Arbiter(self).run()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run      self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt      self.stop()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop      time.sleep(0.1)    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld      self.reap_workers()    File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 528, in reap_workers      raise HaltServer(reason, self.APP_LOAD_ERROR)  gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>
2021-12-13 20:12:02 default[20211213t210314]  "GET /list/ HTTP/1.1" 502
```

Wonder how I could solve this, thanks very much for having a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your application's **requirements.txt** file and include:

```
gunicorn
```

To specify a version:

```
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

The current version of gunicorn is 20.1.0.

[Pypi gunicorn](https://pypi.org/project/gunicorn/)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too - turns my Dockerfile was bad. I had to change:

`CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:server`

To:

`CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app`