# Gunicorn: HaltServer "App failed to load" & "Worker failed to boot"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, plotly-dash

I'm trying to deploy a DashApp to Google Cloud Engine and it keeps saying that my worker either failed to boot or my app failed to load.

```
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>

at
.reap_workers ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:528 )
at
.handle_chld ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:242 )
at
.stop ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:393 )
at
.halt ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:342 )
at
.run ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py:229 )
at
.run ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:72 )
at
.run ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py:231 )
at
.run ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py:67 )
at
.<module> ( /layers/google.python.pip/pip/bin/gunicorn:8 )
```

I am not sure where my error is since I am not using Django or anything and most of the tips is for Django.
It's just a DashApp without anything else, since it is connecting an private API.

Comment: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341778/haltserver-app-failed-to-load-when-deploying-to-google-cloud) which is similar to the issue you encountered. This might help.

Comment: @ku11 please edit your post, include your code, `app.yaml` and `requirement.txt` for us to help you.